# Configure dataframe from text file with python

Tags: python

I am trying to configure a dataframe from a text file with Python (3).

I have a text file like this:

```
ACACIAS
PRIVADO
Calle Francisco de Diego 44, CP: 28040.
    
AGUA DULCE
PÚBLICO
Calle Leñeros 25, CP: 28039.
    
ALARIA ARAVACA ESCUELA INFANTIL
PRIVADO
Calle Barrial 7, CP: 28023.
```

I need to put it into a dataframe like this:

[image]

I have tried to loop over it and append in different lists all lines after the line break and convert to dataframe but I can´t find the way to do it:

```
a_file = open('C:/Users/text.txt', "r")

list_of_lists = []
for line in a_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    line_list = stripped_line.split('/n/n')
    list_of_lists.append(line_list)

pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=['Name', 'Type', 'Address'])
```

Comment: It seems like there are 4 spaces in the space between each row in the text file, perhaps you need to do `line_list = stripped_line.split('/n    /n')` instead of `line_list = stripped_line.split('/n/n')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's better to read all data once, then split them by lines

```
import re

# read file
with open("test.txt", 'r') as file:
    file_data = file.read()
# split items
file_data = re.split(r"\n\s*\n", file_data)
data = []
# split item's elements
for item in file_data:
    elements = item.split("\n")
    data.append({"Name" : elements[0], "Type" : elements[1], "Address" : elements[2]})
# make datframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Hi @Amir Aref. It does work for the first line, but because you are practically adding it manually with the indexing of elements. it stops at elements[2]

Comment: because the text file has some spaces in empty lines, it got wrong, i split it with regex and fix it @vdBurg

Comment: That regular expression did the job! Now I could easily put into a dataframe hundreds of lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do your for loop like this

```
a_file = open('C:/Users/text.txt', "r")

list = []
list_of_lists = []
for line in a_file:
    if line == '    ':
        list_of_lists.append(list)
        list = []
    else:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        list.append(stripped_line)
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=['Name', 'Type', 'Address'])
```

Comment: Hi, @stefan_aus_hannover. You propose to append list, but it´s not defined  when appending